# Search multiple HTML #ID and pass to function

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got an order form, to which I can append fields by clicking a button. I've got some back end JavaScript running which totals up the order price, but the grand total script is eluding me.

My problem is that I need the script to seach the entire DOM and find how many  have an ID which matches the following pattern.

Totprice01
totprice02
totprice03
totprice (n)

I've been playing with this RegExp, but with not a lot of luck I'm afraid:

```
matchStr = new RegExp("\\btotprice\\d{2}\\b", "gi");
```

Once I've got an array of all the HTML IDs I need to pass them into a function which so far looks like this - notice it's all hard coded, not in the least dynamic:

```
document.getElementById('totpricetot').value = Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice1').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice2').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice3').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice4').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice5').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice6').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice7').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice8').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice9').value)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totprice10').value))*100)/100;
```

How do I put this expression + function to return the sum of all the values into `<input id="totpricetot">`?

Comment: There's no need to put that function inside jQuery's ready-function...That's why you can't access it.

Comment: ahh you're kidding me! That was it? all working now - thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could select and sum the elements like this:

```
var sum = 0;
$('[id^=totprice-]').each(function()
{
    sum += $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I love it how every javascript question on SO is answered by, "use jQuery"...

Anyways...you can do it with just plain ol' javascript too:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var priceInputs = [];
for (var i=0, len=inputs.length; i<len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].tagName.indexOf("totprice") > -1) {
        priceInputs[priceInputs.length] = parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
calcTotal(priceInputs);
```

Then just create a function to loop through the array and sum up (:

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of solutions. Besides giving all the elements in question the same class name and use jQuery (or something similar), you could also simply remember the total number of the elements in some JavaScript variable. Would it be possible? I know - it’s kind of an old school solution. You have not indicated that you are using jQuery or any other JavaScript library, so it may be more suitable for you.

**Edit:** Just to be more explicit:

```
// your variable, updated every time you add/remove a new field
var fieldsCount; 

// whenever you need to do anything with all the fields:
for (var i = 0; i < fieldsCount; i++)
{
    var field = document.getElementById("totprice" + i);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: nitpicking, but his ID's are two-digit, so there's probably a need to check the value and pad `i` if it's less than 10. And I like the idea of `fieldsCount`.. +1

Comment: True. I silently assumed that since they are apparently also dynamically created, the numbering can be simply changed :-)

Comment: Thanks, I think originally I was looking for a pure JS solution, but I've been using jquery elsewhere on the site so it made sense to include it here too.

Answer (score 1):

Give the inputs you need to sum up a class and then get those inputs by that class name (jQuery or some other framework would come in handy here).

if you would use jQuery you could do something like this:

```
function calculateSum () {
    var sum = 0;
    $( '.YourClass' ).each ( function () {
        sum += $( this ).val () * 1;
    } );

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give all your total price elements the same CSS class and then get all elements of this class (nice and easy with JQuery).

Answer (score -1):

Give each element a class and use jQuery.